# Ionic 4 Cannot read property

Tags: angular, ionic

Hola estoy intentando imprirmir el get por pantalla pero me sale este error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'played' of undefined

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-tab1',
 templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
 styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {
 matches: any;
 headers: HttpHeaders;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
this.headers = new HttpHeaders({

})
this.http.get('api/competitions',{headers: this.headers
}).subscribe(data => {
  this.matches = data; 
  console.log(this.matches);
});
}
}

<ion-content>
 <ul *ngFor="let match of matches.played;">
<li>{{match}}</li>
</ul>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede declarar matches como:

```
matches:any [] = [];
```

o

```
matches = { played: [] };
```

Comment: Me da este error: The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Property 'played' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type '{ played: any[]; }'. En el this.matches = data;

Comment: Cómo es la estuctura de la data que espera del get?

Comment: No entiendo perdon

Comment: Que recibirá del get?

Comment: Recibe esto: https://pastebin.com/JMiKgAXg

Comment: Y si en vez de dejar this.matches = data; deja this.matches = data.played; y en el *ngFor="let match of matches;"

Comment: console.log(this.matches); te lo imprime en la consola como un json o como un string plano del json?

Answer (score 0):

Entonces en tu componente estas consumiendo tu API para pasar los datos a tu html?, es conveniente separar tu lógica dejando todas las llamadas a tu API a un Provider pero bueno volviendo al tema, quiza el problema este en tu promesa y la vista se cargue antes de que termine tu promesa has intentado agregar await antes de esta?